# TiledMap not drawing completely

Tags: java, libgdx, camera

While attempting to constrain camera scrolling to within the `TiledMap` I discovered that it seems the renderer for the map is not drawing the entire map. The map is 1600x960px so one would assume the setting the camera position to `1600, 960, 0` would result in the top right corner of the map to be centered, however to actually center the map (I had to do some trial and error for this) the coordinates are closer to `1175, 740, 0`.

The map is made of 25x15 tiles and each tile is 64x64px. I initialize the map and renderer like this:

```
    tileMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/" + file);
    renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tileMap, stage.getBatch());
    renderer.setView((OrthographicCamera) stage.getCamera());
```

Then to render I just call `renderer.render()`.

Any idea why this could be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Hard to tell from that alone. Does the same happen with a smaller map? Have you checked that some tiles aren't drawn overlapping? (Where otherwise would the missing tiles go?)

Comment: @Anko Yes, it also happens with a smaller map, and I just counted the tiles and only 18 of the 21 (smaller map) tiles were being drawn. This seems to be because the application size can only fit 18 tiles and the rest aren't being drawn because they aren't on the screen. But shouldn't moving the camera automatically update which tiles are drawn? (How do I check to see if they're overlapping and why would that happen?)

Comment: @Anko The 21 tiles are the width, I made the height 10 tiles (a perfect fit for the screen), so they were all drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to call `renderer.setView(orthoCamera)` to reset the tile map drawing view. Then don't forget to also call `camera.update()` after you do anything to it.